# Tikz and Scientific notation

Tags: tikz-pgf, equations, overlays

I would like to use Tikz to draw something like this:

[image]

```
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\everymath{\displaystyle}\begin{equation*}
{\huge
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!10] (n171)
        {$0,000$};
    }
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!20] (n172)
        {$7$};
    }
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!30] (n173)
        {$82$};
            }
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!40] (n174)
        {$0 $};
    } \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!10,anchor=base] (t172)
        {$7$};
    },
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!20,anchor=base] (t173)
        {$82$};
    } \cdot
    \tikz[baseline]{
        \node[fill=blue!30,anchor=base] (t174)
        {$\num{e-4}$};
}
}
\end{equation*}\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
    \path[->] (n172) edge [out=90, in=90] (t172);
    \path[->] (n173) edge [out=-90, in=-90] (t173);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Is there any way to do this better? Thanks

Comment: You are pretty close. Some minor tips: (1) you are filling nodes by `fill=blue!40`, which results in rectangles of variant sizes. Instead, draw a separate rectangle and color it so you can control its size. (2) rounded corners. (3) tune the angles in `out=90, in=90` and use fancy arrow tips `-latex`. (4) for text like `zati osoa`, you can attach a node to an edge by `\draw(A)edge node{zati}(B);`. (5) for `idazkera...`, search for `Decoration brace`.

Comment: @Symbol1. I have tested your indications but I do not know how to reduce the space between the nodes. Thanks again.

Comment: something like `outer sep=-2pt` should help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have tried the indications given by @Symbol 1 and this is what I have achieved. Thanks again.

```
\tikzstyle{every picture}+=[remember picture]
\everymath{\displaystyle}
\begin{minipage}[b]{0.8\textwidth}
\hfill\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decorate,decoration=brace,very thick] (3,0) -- (10,0)node [midway, above=2pt] {\Large {Idazkera zientifikoa}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{equation*}
{\huge
        \tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
%        \draw[rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (1.6,0.8);
        \draw (0,0.4) node(n171)
            {$0,000$};
        }
        \hspace{-.3cm}\tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw[dashed, red, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.6,0.8);
        \draw (0.3,0.4) node(n172)
            {$7$};
        }
        \hspace{-.2cm}\tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw[dashed, blue, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
        \draw (0.4,0.4) node(n173)
            {$82$};
                }
        \hspace{-.3cm}\tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw (0,0.4) node(n174)
            {$0 $};
        }
        \tikz[baseline]{
        \draw (0.2,0.4) node(n176)
            {$\Longrightarrow$};
        }% \quad \Longrightarrow \quad
        \tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw[red, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.6,0.8);
        \draw (0.3,0.4) node(t172)
            {$7$};
        \node [red,above](osoa) at (t172.north) {\Large osoa};
        \node [red,above] at (osoa.north){\Large Zati};
        }
        \hspace{-.8cm}\tikz[baseline]{
        \draw (0,0) node(n176)
            {$,$};
        }
        \hspace{-1.4cm}\tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw[blue,rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (0.8,0.8);
        \draw (0.4,0.4) node(t173)
            {$82$};
        \node [blue,below](zati) at (t173.south) {\Large Zati};
        \node [blue,below] at (zati.south){\Large hamartarra};
        }
        \hspace{-1.4cm}\tikz[baseline]{
        \draw (0,0.4) node(n176)
            {$\times$};
        }
        \hspace{-.4cm}\tikz[baseline,outer sep=-2pt]{
        \draw[green, rounded corners] (0,0) rectangle (1.4,0.8);
        \draw (0.7,0.4) node(t174)
            {$\num{e-4}$};
        \node [green,above right] at (100:0.9) {\Large 10en berretura};
                }
 }
 \end{equation*}


\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]
        \path[-latex,red,very thick] (n172) edge [out=45, in=135] (t172);
        \path[-latex,blue,very thick] (n173) edge [out=-45, in=-135] (t173);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{minipage}
```

[image]